# How to get responce code and error message from retrofit 2.4.0 in Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

while signing up, I am unable to get the response code and error message so can you help me?

This is My Interface

```
public interface SignupAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("users")
Call<ResponseBody> createUser(
    @Field("email") String email,
    @Field("password") String password,
    @Field("role") String role
);
}
```

This is Java Class

```
public class SignupClient {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/";
private static SignupClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private SignupClient(){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
}
public static synchronized SignupClient getmInstance(){
if (mInstance == null){
    mInstance = new SignupClient();
}
return mInstance;
}
public SignupAPI getApi(){
    return retrofit.create(SignupAPI.class);
}
}
```

This Is Signup Activity

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Call<ResponseBody> call = SignupClient.getmInstance().getApi().createUser(email, password,role);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Account Sucessfully Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        try {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            JSONObject jsonError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, jsonError.getString("errors"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I am not able to get error message and also response code so please help me to get it.

Here is the Postman [PostMan API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Woy.png)

Comment: response.body().string() is also not working

Comment: response.code(), response.error().string() is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written how you can get HTTP code from both success response and error response.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    int statusCode = response.code(); 
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    if (new Exception(t) instanceof HttpException) {
        int statusCode = ((HttpException) t).getStatusCode();
    else {
        // unknown error
    }
}
```